# Getall dependencies of an npm package with recursion Elixir

Tags: elixir

I have this url `@registry "http://registry.npmjs.org/"` when you append package name and `/latest`  with it returns you some details about a package, I need to fetch all its dependencies which I did and its working fine but I need to go more level down, with it. such as.

If you check `http://registry.npmjs.org/handlebars/latest` and it has 4 dependencies, And I want these `deps` as well as go further with `neo-async` as well as other `deps` and `deps` of these `deps` to get what are their dependencies. I have tried this.

```
defmodule Deep do
  @registry "http://registry.npmjs.org/"

  alias HTTPoison.Response, as: Resp

  def go(package, complete_deps \\ []) do
    HTTPoison.get(@registry <> package <> "/latest")
    |> handle_response()
    |> get_deps()
  end

  defp get_deps(nil),  do: []
  defp get_deps(deps),  do: Enum.map(deps, fn({k, _v}) -> k end)

  defp handle_response({:ok, %Resp{status_code: 200, body: body}}), do:
    Poison.decode!(body)["dependencies"]
  defp handle_response(_), do: nil
end
```

But I end up on the very first level yet, I tried

get_deps results to do head and tail, to go further with deps but I have no idea where I can save the tail or all the deps.

Basically, I want to get handlebars, deps, and the deps of its all deps as well in one list using recursion, I can see a solution with Enum.map but it will be bit ugly. Any help would be thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code will build the dependency tree.

It depends on [`jason`](https://github.com/michalmuskala/jason) Elixir package and uses [`httpc`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/httpc.html) HTTP client shipped in Erlang standard library. Using these vs. using [`poison`](https://hex.pm/packages/poison) and [`httpoison`](https://hex.pm/packages/httpoison) has the advantage of lowering the number of code dependencies from **8** to **1**:

```
defmodule Deep do
  @registry 'http://registry.npmjs.org/'

  def go([]), do: []
  def go([dep | other_deps]), do: [go(dep) | go(other_deps)]
  def go(package) do
    deps =
      [@registry, to_charlist(package), '/latest']
      |> :httpc.request()
      |> handle_response()
      |> get_deps()

    if Enum.empty?(deps), do: package, else: {package, go(deps)}
  end

  defp get_deps(nil), do: []
  defp get_deps(deps), do: Map.keys(deps)

  defp handle_response({:ok, {{_, 200, _}, _headers, body}}),
    do: Jason.decode!(body)["dependencies"]

  defp handle_response(_), do: nil
end
```

The output:

```
iex(1)> Deep.go("handlebars")
{"handlebars",
 [
   "neo-async",
   {"optimist", ["minimist", "wordwrap"]},
   "source-map",
   {"uglify-js", ["commander", "source-map"]}
 ]}
iex(2)>
```

Comment: dont you think its an overdo?

Comment: @JunaidFarooq what do you find excessive about the solution?

Comment: that clean and version part.

Comment: @JunaidFarooq do you suggest fetching `latest` version for each dependency package?

Comment: yes, and then you don't need to put latest in the tuple as well

Comment: @JunaidFarooq noted. I didn't realize you don't need versions in the end result. I've updated my answer by taking your code as a basis. May I ask why do you consider a solution based on recursion with `Enum.map` to be ugly?

Comment: Enum.map and Each those are kind of loops for me in ruby.

Comment: @JunaidFarooq I've updated the answer to get rid of `Enum.map`

Comment: Okay thanks I have accepted it, but I think the results should be in one long list. :)

Answer (score 0):

To get all the unique dependencies in one flat list:

```
defmodule Deep do
  @registry "http://registry.npmjs.org/"

  alias HTTPoison.Response, as: Resp

  def go(package) do
    HTTPoison.get(@registry <> package <> "/latest")
    |> handle_response()
    |> get_deps()
    |> List.flatten()
    |> Enum.uniq()
  end

  defp get_deps(nil),  do: []
  defp get_deps(deps),  do: Enum.map(deps, fn({k, _v}) -> [k | go(k)] end)

  defp handle_response({:ok, %Resp{status_code: 200, body: body}}), do:
    Poison.decode!(body)["dependencies"]
  defp handle_response(_), do: nil
end
```

Usage:

```
iex(11)> Deep.go("handlebars")             
["neo-async", "optimist", "minimist", "wordwrap", "source-map", "uglify-js",
 "commander"]
```